# How to convert text into URL syntax on Python?

Tags: python, url

I want to convert Python string to URL syntax.

For example

```
>>> u'한글'.encode('utf-8')
'\xed\x95\x9c\xea\xb8\x80' to '%ed%95%9c%ea%b8%80'
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
>>> import urllib2
>>> urllib2.quote('한글')
'%ED%95%9C%EA%B8%80'
```

Comment: This depends on the terminal or source file being UTF-8, of course. The ‘safe’ spelling would be `urllib.quote(u'\ud55c\uae00'.encode('utf-8'))`.